# JavaFX, moving nodes in a GridPane with arrow keys

Tags: java, javafx, nodes, eventhandler, gridpane

I am struggling with a maze-like game. I am trying to move a "player"-node around in a GridPane using the arrow keys.

This is my event handler: 
    public class KeyListener implements EventHandler {

```
public KeyListener(Player player, int prevX, int prevY, GridPane mapGrid) {
    this.player = player;
    this.prevX = prevX;
    this.prevY = prevY;
    this.mapGrid = mapGrid;
}

// Method for finding rectangle in gridpane:
private Node getNode(GridPane gridPane, int col, int row) {
    for (Node node : gridPane.getChildren()) {
        if (GridPane.getColumnIndex(node) == col && GridPane.getRowIndex(node) == row) {
            return node;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Player goes " + event.getCode());
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
            this.player.setPosX(prevX);
            this.player.setPosY(prevY + 1);
            Node targetNode = getNode(mapGrid, prevX, prevY+1);
            System.out.println(targetNode.toString());
            System.out.println(this.player.getPosX() + " " + this.player.getPosY());
            mapGrid.add(this.player.playerLook(), player.getPosX(), player.getPosY()); }
```

Covering only what happens if the arrowdown-key is pressed. 
My problem is that the node moves down one row after the first keypress, but after that it does not work any more, but the System.out.println("Player goes " + event.getCode()) sentence is printed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, the player's position only updates after the first event.

Comment: My guess is that your handler is only registered for the initial position/node. You would have to remove the event handler on the old node and add it on the new one, however there is not enough code to go on to be sure, that is what is happening.

Comment: I added the handler to the main scene in my Main class. I've also tried adding it to the GridPane itself.

Comment: The issue is that you don't update prevX and prevY. You must show me the whole code to answer, but I'm assuming setPosX and setPosY does not mutate prevX or prevY. Therefore, at first iteration, when prevY == posY, it works, but then when prevY == (posY - 1), it becomes posY = prevY + 1, therefore staying at the same location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not provided enough information, I will make some assumptions.

You should mutate `prevX` and `prevY`. If you have a setter method for `prevY`,

```
this.player.setPrevY(this.player.getPrevY() + 1);
```

As explained in the comment, at first iteration, `prevY == posY`.

Then, it mutates `posY` into `prevY + 1`. Therefore `posY = prevY + 1`. The character moves.

In the second iteration, `posY = prevY + 1`. Therefore, even when you set `this.player.setPosY(prevY + 1)`, it remains at the same location.

Comment: You make some good points, Steven. I'll give your advice a shot when I get back home tonight.

Comment: Actually, I do call the KeyListener from my Main using the player's current position. I've just called it prevX and prevY inside the handler itself.

Comment: I use the getters for posX and posY as argument when calling the KeyListener.

Comment: So what`s the point of sending separate prevX and prevY? Why not just use player.getPos() inside of the handler and just pass the player in? It will reduce a lot of confusion. Debug by Printing prevX, prevY, player.getPosX() and player.getPosY()

Comment: What did you do to make it work? I'm glad. You're welcome. Good luck in the future and if you have any more questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: I thought I had all the references in order, but after only using getters for the player's position it works like a charm!